# Bash autocomplete: select random suggestion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Basically I want a way for figlet to choose a random font. It doesn't seem to have an inbuilt method, or at least I haven't found one in the manual or in the web.

I want the message to pop up every time I open up a new xterm, which is easy enough adding
`figlet -f <a font> Hello World`
to bash.rc

But I also want the font to be random. I'm wondering if there is a way for `<a font>` to be selected randomly from the autocomplete suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't appear to have autocompletion for figlet. And even if it did, I don't think there's a generic way to generate completions for a specific context, you have to know how the completion code works for this particular command.

You can, however, list the functions without reference to the completion code. Mimicking the [zsh completion code](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_figlet), the fonts are `*.flf` files in the directory shown by `figlet -I2`. The font names are the file base names, but you can actually pass a full path to a file.

```
figlet_fonts=("$(figlet -I2)"/*.flf)
```

So what remains to be done is to take a random element of this array. The special variable [`RANDOM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-RANDOM) yields a random number each time it's read. Divide by the size of the array and take the remainder to get a random array index. (There's a slight bias towards the beginning of the array, which doesn't matter here.)

```
figlet -f "${figlet_fonts[$RANDOM % ${#figlet_fonts[@]}]}" Hello world
```

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly! Exactly the outcome I wanted.

Comment: Found another method using shuf and kind of combined it with yours `figlet -f $(ls "$(figlet -I2)"/*.flf | shuf -n1) Hello World !`

Comment: And of course you can go really crazy with `figlet -f $(ls $(figlet -I2)/*.flf | shuf -n1) Hello World ! | cowsay -n -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/ | shuf -n1) | lolcat`